# Rewrite everything, including actual files/directories to one file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This rewrites everything, but actual files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

How do I rewrite "everything" to `index.php`, including actual file requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the 2 RewriteCond lines with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php/
```

This will prevent a rewrite loop, and your RewriteRule is already setup to rewrite everything (the condition was preventing you from rewriting existing files)

Comment: Results in 500, changing it to `!index.php` did it tho'. So, what is the reason behind all that slashing-up?

Comment: Hmm, but with simply `!index.php` it doesn't rewrite deeper `index.php` files, therefore parses those instead.

Comment: Crap, it's supposed to be *REQUEST_URI*, not *REQUEST_FILENAME*, sorry (and edited). Sorry, typed it without thinking.